# Can we integrate Sensors to blender

Tags: game-engine, external-applications

I wanted to Build a physical Game in sense of having an external sensor like heart rate or light sensor sending data to Blender engine and use these data to move object or do something within the game so is there a way Blender can handle external sensors

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to do this with an Arduino, I don't know if it would work without.

Comment: so its possible with Arduino then i am good with that but how to do it i mean the code that used by Blender to open the port and communicate with Arduino

Answer (score 2):

While i havent seen it doen inside the game engine, it has been done inside blender. there is a great stack exchange answer here [How to move an Arduino's servo motors using Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6494/how-to-move-an-arduinos-servo-motors-using-blender)

To use this in the game engine you would need to modify the python code to use the game engine modules, and connect it as a python script controller in the game panel.

Answer (score 0):

This sample maybe userful

https://github.com/OpenDevice/opendevice-examples/tree/master/opendevice-3d-blender

It makes the integration with OpenDevice(Java) and Blender (Python)

Allowing you to make any kind of communication with the Arduino (Bluetooth, USB, ethernet, wifi), the OpenDevice does the dirty work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3PbOPIMHmY