# is there a way to export data realtime from blender?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, export

I am very interested in blenders inverse kinematics and I would like to make a robot that runs on this.

example: I want to make so when I move a bone in blender my robot in real life will move as well.

or: at least make it so that I could export animation(rotation values of bones in time) from blender in some sort of matrix format

Comment: do you mean using the rotation or position of a bone in blender to drive a output to a servo motor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move an Arduino's servo motors using Blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6494/how-to-move-an-arduinos-servo-motors-using-blender)

Comment: A rotation. I want to make a robot hand like in the industry.