# How to do a simulation on blender for an exoskeleton

Tags: modeling, rigid-body-simulation

I m working on a similar project as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlfW1nK9fcE&list=PLCkl1Wyi7jvBsDe-5tZzDH493HFY3Mrvj&index=14&t=0s):

Could you guys tell me how it is possible to implemeent a simulation as such using a range of sensors?
I have no idea how it could be done.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move an Arduino's servo motors using Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6494/how-to-move-an-arduinos-servo-motors-using-blender)

Comment: try to explain "as such" somehow, refer to your current setup, what doesn't work, in a simplest form...